# QFileSystemModel QTableView Date Modified highlighting

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qfilesystemmodel

I am trying to make a little file browser using QFileSystemModel and QTableView.

I was wondering if it is possible to highlight rows with same value in "Date Modified" column, for instance if I have two or more files which been modified today row gets highlighted in green,
those modified yesterday highlighted in green but lighter shade, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the background color there are several options such as:

- override the `data()` method of the model so that the return value associated with the role `Qt.BackgroundRole`.
- Use a QIdentityProxyModel that modifies the value associated with `Qt.BackgroundRole` similar to the previous option
- Use a `QStyledItemDelegate` to modify the `backgroundBrush` property of `QStyleOptionViewItem`.

The simplest option is the last option so I will show your implementation:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class DateDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        model = index.model()
        if isinstance(model, QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel):
            dt = model.lastModified(index)

            today = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
            yesterday = today.addDays(-1)
            if dt < yesterday:
                option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
            else:
                option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QColor(0, 155, 0)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    path_dir = QtCore.QDir.currentPath()

    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    view.setModel(model)
    model.setRootPath(path_dir)

    view.setRootIndex(model.index(path_dir))

    view.show()

    delegate = DateDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```